# Php update multiple row with checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

Hello i would like to UPDATE all the row with a Boolean ( 1 ) when i check the checkbox , but i can't do it when i try.. He select and update all "$id" or update only the last $id of my cours table.

Someone can help ? :)

EDIT :

```
 <form action='' method='POST'>

        <?php


        require 'inc/db.php';
        $req = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM cours WHERE isValid = 0' );
        while ($row = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $originalDate = $row['date'];
            $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($newDate) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['hours']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['iduser']) . " / " . htmlspecialchars($row['lastname']) . " / " . htmlspecialchars($row['firstname']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['courses']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check[$id]' value='1' >" . $id . "</td> ";
            print "</tr>";
        }
        print "</table>";

                if(isset($_POST['check']) && count($_POST['check'] )) {
                $ids = implode($_POST['check']);
                $req2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cours SET isValid = 1 WHERE id IN ({$ids})");
                $req2->execute();
                var_dump($_POST['check']);

                }


        ?>
            <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary center-block" >send</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['check']) && count($_POST['check'])) {
   $ids = implode(', ', $_POST['check']);
   $sql = "UPDATE cours SET isValid = 1 WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
   //run sql
}
```

Of course, it's still as vulnerable to sql injection as your current code. You'd want to either ensure all the ids are actually integers, or use parameters in your statement.

You may be having trouble debugging this, because you put your var_dump outside the loop. So you're only ever going to SEE the last id.

Comment: Hum still didn't work .. With your code i only update the first $id :/

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['check']);` - what is dumped?

Comment: When i do a var_dump the 3rd checkbox =  array (size=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1) 
So it's ok in var_dump , but when update with the request it's like 1 => 1 always :/

Comment: I just realized you're doing the `<form>` tag inside the loop. You have a bunch of forms instead of one.

Comment: Post your updated code and the results of the var_dump

Comment: i edited my post , for exemple if i check the second chebox and submit the  var_dump return : array (size=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: Okay, so what is the problem?

Comment: So here a screen : http://www.noelshack.com/2015-30-1437498395-sans-titre-1.png 
when i select the $id 3 .. he should UPDATE but nothing happens .. But if I go into my phpmyadmin and I reset the isValid to 0 value for the id '1', it works, but always and only for id = 1 .. > <

Comment: The value of your checkboxes is all 1, you should make the value of the checkbox the id.

Comment: Oh god thx work well ! But it didin't when i select multiple checkbox and submit :/